# View's column contains data which looks like UUID but the column type is int. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqldatatypes

I've access to a view on a SQL Server 2016 database.

The column named 'id_key' contains such data:

```
id_key
D93F37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502
B03D37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502
AC644CFC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502
```

I've checked the type of the column: it's `int`

Truly, the result of:

```
    SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumnName'
```

returns just `int`.

I've not found any explanation for that in SQL Server 2016 docs.
Have I missed something?
How `int` type store data which looks like strings/uuids?

Comment: That value certainly doesn't look like an `int` to me.  Perhaps you are querying the wrong database or schema.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that I've checked the column type of the correct view. I did that by a query, but also I see the `int` column type in my DbClient.

Comment: Can you create a [mre] as a DBFiddle?

Comment: I wish I could, but I have no idea how to reproduce it.
I have read-only access to just a single view from the whole DB server.

I've checked its DDL and it goes like:

`CREATE VIEW db_name.my_view as select ov.id_key, ov.other_column FROM  db_name.other_view as a;`

As I've written in the question, I've no access to underlying views/tables of this view.
So I've no idea how to reproduce it, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the view was not created using the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option then the underlying tables that it references are freely able to change.

It is possible that the problematic column was originally using an `int` data type when the view was created but has subsequently changed to `uniqueidentifier`, e.g.:

```sql
drop view if exists dbo.yourViewName;
drop table if exists dbo.yourTableName;
go
create table dbo.yourTableName (
    ignore int,
    yourColumnName int
);
go
create view dbo.yourViewName --with schemabinding
as
    select yourColumnName as id_key
    from dbo.yourTableName
go
alter table dbo.yourTableName
    drop column yourColumnName
go
alter table dbo.yourTableName
    add yourColumnName uniqueidentifier
go
insert dbo.yourTableName (yourColumnName) values
    ('D93F37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502'),
    ('B03D37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502'),
    ('AC644CFC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502')
go
select * from dbo.yourViewName
go
select data_type
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'yourViewName'
and column_name = 'id_key'
```

Which yields:

```
id_key
------------------------------------
D93F37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502
B03D37FC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502
AC644CFC-3C2A-EB11-B813-00505690E502

data_type
----------
int
```

See the [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) documentation for more information.

Comment: Yes! That was it! I've received a response from the person who created the view, and he confirmed that when the view was created, the underlying type was int. Then the underlying type has changed to uniqueidentifier, so exactly how you described it.
Thanks for the perfect explanation!